# Использование Enum вместе с ComboBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени форумчане.
У меня есть такой вопрос. Итак, допустим, у меня есть `ComboBox` на форме, в котором перечислены страны, рядом с ним находится `PictureBox` для изображения флага каждой из стран. В `Enum` я могу поместить для каждого индекса `ComboBox` путь к изображению через ресурсы. Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе нужного индекса подставлялось изображение, если использовать `if` код получится слишком грязный, громоздкий.
Спасибо

На данный момент попробовал такой вариант. Параметром передается индекс выбранного айтема в `ComboBox`

```
public static Image GetFlatСountry(int index)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                {
                    return Properties.Resources.russia;
                }
            case 1:
                {
                    return Properties.Resources.united_states;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    return Properties.Resources.ukraine;
                }
            case 3:
                {
                    return Properties.Resources.poland;
                }
            case 4:
                {
                    return Properties.Resources.romania;
                }
            default:
                {
                    return Properties.Resources.error;
                }
        }
    }
```

Применение

```
iconCountry.Image = GetFlatСountry(listCountry.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: Если у вас вопрос по коду - приведите код. Иначе это обсуждение абстрактных коней в вакууме получается.

Comment: @tym32167 Если честно, я и сам как это с трудом понимаю, думал направят на нужную мысль, как решать такую проблему

Comment: `enum` не предназначен для хранения данных. Точка. Используйте словарь или другую коллекцию. Но для начала покажите код, что там с чем вам надо спарить. Хотя-бы на примере из трех значений.

Comment: @aepot кажется через `switch` будет удобнее, нежели через enum

Comment: `enum` - это перечисление, `switch` - это оператор. Вы сказали что-то типа "кажется огурцы вкуснее, нежели бегать по утрам"

Comment: @aepot ага, спасибо вам еще раз)

Comment: Перестаньте называть SO форумом! Это сайт, где сообщество совместными силами собирает полезное и интересное не только самим авторам, но и будущим читателям. То есть вы приходите сюда тогда, когда у вас есть интересных вопрос и вы хотите найти на него решение, либо у вас наоборот есть хорошее решение для поставленной задачи и вы хотите им поделиться с сообществом. Если вы чего-то не понимаете, то стоит в первую очередь поискать информацию самостоятельно, попробовать решить это все, а уж затем, если затрудняетесь, приходите сюда со своими наработками и спрашиваете, но не как иначе...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`switch` здесь выглядит нормально. При использовании .NET Core и новее, ваш код можно записать так

```cs
public static Image GetFlatСountry(int index) => index switch
{
    0 => Properties.Resources.russia,
    1 => Properties.Resources.united_states,
    2 => Properties.Resources.ukraine,
    3 => Properties.Resources.poland,
    4 => Properties.Resources.romania,
    _ => Properties.Resources.error
};
```

```cs
Image image = GetFlatСountry(0);
```

А вообще можно еще создать словарь

```cs
private static readonly Dictionary<int, Image> FlatСountries = new Dictionary<int, Image>
{
    [0] = Properties.Resources.russia,
    [1] = Properties.Resources.united_states,
    [2] = Properties.Resources.ukraine,
    [3] = Properties.Resources.poland,
    [4] = Properties.Resources.romania
}

public static Image GetFlatСountry(int index)
    => FlatСountries.TryGetValue(index, out Image image) ? image : Properties.Resources.error;
```

Но первый вариант мне кажется уместнее, так как не требует дополнительной памяти для хранения словаря.